# Missing Words in PyDictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydictionary

PyDictionary is a Dictionary Module for Python that can be used to get meanings of words:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()

print (dictionary.meaning("word"))
```

Output:

> {'Noun': ['a unit of language that native speakers can identify', 'a brief statement', 'information about recent and important events', 'a verbal command for action', 'an exchange of views on some topic', 'a promise', 'a string of bits stored in computer memory', 'the divine word of God; the second person in the Trinity (incarnate in Jesus', 'a secret word or phrase known only to a restricted group', 'the sacred writings of the Christian religions'], 'Verb': ['put into words or an expression']}

But if I search for other words like "the" (which is the most frequently used word in the English language):

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()

print (dictionary.meaning("the"))
```

Output:

> Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
> None

How is it that the most frequently used word in English doesn't appear in a dictionary?, is there a way to add articles, prepositions and conjunctions to the Python dictionary?

Comment: You are question was answered [here](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/issues/33)

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize what @shaikmoeed said.

https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/

*PyDictionary is a Dictionary Module for Python 2/3 to get meanings, translations, synonyms and Antonyms of words. It uses **WordNet** for getting meanings*

**PyDictionary uses Wordnet.**

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn

---

[image]

---

and there is no meaning for the word **'the'** in WordNet

---

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is another library that adds those words? I suppose that I can add them manually in a python dictionary (the data type), but I was wondering if it already existed

Comment: I tried to search, I thought `nltk` would have something. But, unfortunately it is also importing `wordnet`. `from nltk.corpus import wordnet `